# Проблема с скетчем Arduino (или командой)

Tags: arduino, port

Мотор должен сделать 100 шагов, если на Arduino пришла единица.
Отправляю ее командой 
`$ echo "1">/dev/ttyACM0` (на `/dev/ttyACM0` крутится Arduino).
Но ничего не происходит.

Ниже представлен код скетча.

Питания хватает, кабель нормальный, пины подключены правильно.

**UPD**

Arduino внезапно поменяла свое местоположение на `/dev/ttyACM1`.
Делаю ей `$ echo "1">/dev/ttyACM1`. Индикатор вращения двигателя загорается, но сам он не вращается. В чем причина?
Использую [этот](http://wiki.amperka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B:troyka:stepper) драйвер для шагового двигателя.

```
const byte stepPin = 2;
const byte directionPin = 1;
const byte enablePin = 3;
int delayTime = 20;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(directionPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  int DistanceByte = Serial.read();
  if (DistanceByte == 1) {
  digitalWrite(enablePin, HIGH);
 // Задаём направление вращения по часовой стрелке
  digitalWrite(directionPin, HIGH);
 // Делаем 50 шагов
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // Делаем шаг
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
  } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, в терминал вы печатаете цифру 1?
Тогда ваша проблема решается так:
вместо

```
if (DistanceByte == 1)
```

пишите

```
if (DistanceByte == '1')
```

Почитайте про [кодировки символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Не помогло. Еще варианты?

Comment: Плата Uno? Попробуйте открыть монитор порта и послать 1 в нём. Работает?

Comment: @VanyambaElectrnics, Leonardo. Сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1. Команда

   echo 1 > /dev/ttyACM0

будет работать только в случае, если порт настроен правильно. Чтобы его настроить, нужно подать команду

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 0:4:cbd:0:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:0:0:11:13:1a:0:12:f:17:16:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

2. Чтобы мотор заработал, ему нужно подать питание, которое по USB получить нельзя. То есть требуется внешний блок питания. Думаю, причина в этом.

Comment: Я понимаю, что команда работает только в случае нахождения устройства на данном порте. Я дополнил уже давно вопрос на эту тему, и решил его.
Насчет внешнего блока, вы не правы. Все прекрасно работает и без него.